# Creating drop-shadow for items for QGIS Print Layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Using QGIS 3.4.4, I've added a map to a print layout, given it a black frame, and it looks fine.

Now how do I add a drop-shadow effect to the map frame in the layout?

I haven't found anything in the layout's properties that would create such an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a bug. The drop shadow is still drawn, so I just offset the x and y of the simple fill to a negative for now to show the shadow.

Answer (score 4):

[Material Desing Map With Qgis Composer](https://underdark.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/material_qgis_tutorial_final.pdf) on page 3 shows how the author achieved a drop shadow effect by creating a  box  with  add  rectangle and without border settings and then uses Offset, Blur radius and Transparency.

I should also add that the version used in the blog is not stated.

Comment: According to your link, the drop shadow is created on a separate rectangle graphic, which is then placed under the map item, with the drop shadow "peeking out" from underneath.  It works fine under 2.18.  With 3.4.4. I accessed  the drop shadow by r-click the rectangle > item properties > click simple fill > checkbox draw effects > click yellow star > check on drop shadow.  But, the drop shadow fails to offset from the rectangle.  Possibly a bug?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out (as regards my being able to comment on a post).

Indeed, it does look like the author in the link did use 2.18. Hopefully someone who uses your version of the software helps soon.